# Insert Multiple Rows From Database An Into Database B With Single SQL Command

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table named 'Customers' which it contains customer's phone number. Its definitely more than one row.

On the other hand, I also have database named 'SMS' with a table in it, called 'Outbox'.

In order to show all phone number from 'Customers' table, I use this SQL query:

```
SELECT Customers.PhoneNumber FROM Customers WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-01-31;
```

Now, I need those phone numbers (multiple rows) to be inserted into 'Outbox' at once. Every phone number will receive same message. So, basically I just need to know how to use this INSERT query for multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO Outbox (PhoneNumber, Message) VALUES (*Multiple PhoneNumbers Here*, 'Same Message To All Customers');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want a separate row for each phone number.  You can do this by combining INSERT with SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO db2.Outbox (PhoneNumber, Message)
    SELECT Customers.PhoneNumber, 'Same Message To All Customers' as message
    FROM db1.Customers
    WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-01-31;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Outbox (PhoneNumber, Message) 
SELECT Customers.PhoneNumber,  'Same Message To All Customers' as Message 
FROM Customers 
WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-01-31;
```

Should do you

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbX.table_a
    SELECT ...
        FROM dbY.table_b
        WHERE ...
```

You don't **have** to specify anything in the inserts' value list if you make sure the selects' column list matches dbX.table_a entirely.